# automatic UIScrollView with paging

Tags: objective-c, timer, uiscrollview, nstimer, uipagecontrol

I have a UIScrollView with paging enabled. However i want this scrollview to scroll right when a certain amount of time has passed. Is there a easy way to implement this or do i need to use a timer and programmatically scroll the scrollview?

Something like this website has in its header: http://denederlandsewateren.nl/ [notice the text "De Nederlandse Wateren" changes each x seconds]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on stackoverflow

```
[scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(x, y) animated:YES];
```

To do slideshows with UIScrollView, you arrange all images in the scroll view, set up a repeated timer, then -setContentOffset:animated: when the timer fires.

Answer (score 14):

You need a little method to help you scroll to the exact page, this is not implemented, but it's very simple, let's assume your scrollview is called `myScrollview`

This assumes you're scrolling horizontally, you can switch the code to fit your needs

```
-(void)scrollToPage:(NSInteger)aPage{
    float myPageWidth = [myScrollView frame].size.width;
    [myScrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(aPage*myPageWidth,y) animated:YES];
}
```

Then you setup a timer to call this method every 5 seconds for example, like this:

```
[[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                  target:self
                                selector:@selector(scrollPages)
                                userInfo:Nil
                                 repeats:YES] fire];
```

Next step is to create the method that will be fired by the timer and scroll to the next page, I called it `-(void)scrollPages`, it also requires that you have two global variables called `currentPage` and `numberOfPages`, both are of type `NSInteger`

```
-(void)scrollPages{
    [self scrollToPage:currentPage%numberOfPages];
    currentPage++;
}
```

If something doesn't make sense let me know !

Comment: Great overview. One question: in an ARC environment, do we need to strongly hold on to the NSTimer to ensure it doesn't disappear on us?

Comment: It depends on what you're doing, `schuduleTimerWithTimeInterval` will add it to a runloop for you, which means you'll always get a call to `scrollPages`, if you add an `id sender` to `scrollPages` to become `-(void)scrollPages:(id) sender;`, your sender will be the timer that called this method, from there you can simply invalidate the timer without having to worry about references !

The other way is to just strongly reference it in your class and invalidate it any other place in your code as you said!

Comment: for swift ```let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width
        scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: page * Int(pageWidth), y: 0), animated: true)```

Answer (score 0):

In your .h file create outlets for scrollview and paging

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *sliderScrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPageControl *sliderPageControll;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *sliderImagesArray;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *sliderIndexString;
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *currentPageIndexString;
```

after that in your .m file

```
[self.sliderScrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[self.sliderScrollView setBounces:NO];
[self.sliderScrollView setAlwaysBounceVertical:NO];
[self.sliderScrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
self.sliderScrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = NO;
NSArray *imagesArray = self.sliderImagesArray;
for (int i = 0; i < [imagesArray count]; i++){
            CGFloat xOrigin = i * self.imageSliderScrollView.frame.size.width;
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xOrigin, 0, self.sliderScrollView.frame.size.width, self.sliderScrollView.frame.size.height)];
                imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    NSString *imgStr = [serviceImgArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *bikeStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imgStr];
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[bikeStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageURL
                       placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"profilepic_bg"]];
[imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
                [self.sliderScrollView addSubview:imageView];
}
// for adding autorotate scrolling
   [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(autoStartSlide:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

self.sliderPageControll.numberOfPages = imagesArray.count;
self.sliderPageControll.currentPage = 0;
self.currentPageIndexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)0];
[self.sliderScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.sliderScrollView.frame.size.width * [imagesArray count], self.sliderScrollView.frame.size.height)];

if ([self.sliderPageControll respondsToSelector:@selector(setPageIndicatorTintColor:)]) {
    self.sliderPageControll.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.sliderPageControll.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

CGRect frame = self.sliderScrollView.frame;
frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.sliderIndexString] integerValue];
frame.origin.y = 0;
[self.sliderScrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO];
self.sliderPageControll.currentPage = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.sliderIndexString] integerValue];
```

after that implement scrollview delegate method

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
NSInteger scrollIndex = (NSInteger)(self.sliderScrollView.contentOffset.x / self.sliderScrollView.frame.size.width);
self.sliderPageControll.currentPage = scrollIndex;
self.currentPageIndexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)self.sliderPageControll.currentPage];
}
```

Here implement your autotrotate method.

```
 - (void)autoStartSlide:(id)sender {
if(pagger.numberOfPages > pagger.currentPage+1) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        slider.contentOffset = CGPointMake(slider.contentOffset.x + slider.frame.size.width, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
else {
    slider.contentOffset = CGPointMake(slider.contentOffset.x - slider.frame.size.width, 0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        slider.contentOffset = CGPointMake(slider.contentOffset.x + slider.frame.size.width, 0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        slider.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0) ;
    }];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Swift 5 Compatible one

```
var currentPage = 1;
var slideTimer : Timer?
```

ViewDidLoad

```
 slideTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 3, target: self, selector: #selector(scrollPages), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

viewDidDisappear

```
slideTimer?.invalidate()
```

Functions

```
@objc func scrollPages() {
        scrollToPage(page: CGFloat(currentPage%slides.count));
        currentPage+=1;
    }
    
    func scrollToPage(page : CGFloat) {
        let pageWidth = scrollView.frame.width
        scrollView .setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: pageWidth * page, y: 0.0), animated: true)
    }
```